# How can I traverse up the tree to add an 'active' class to my menu on buttons depending on user site location?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make 'menu on' buttons that highlight when a user is in a specific folder. There are examples on S.O. that have helped me, but I need traverse up the tree to set the 'active' class.

```
var current = location.pathname;

$('nav dl dt a').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   // if the current path is like this link, make it active
   if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
       ($this).parents('nav dl dt').addClass('menuOn');
   }
});
```

I have to traverse because of my HTML structure:

```js
var current = location.pathname;

$('nav dl dt a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // if the current path is like this link, make it active
  // Commenting following condition for testing.
  //if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
  ($this).parents('nav dl dt').addClass('menuOn');
  //}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuWrapper">
  <nav id="nav">
    <div id="menuArea">
      <dl class="menuAreas">
        <dt class="menuButtonHolder" id="menu0">
            <a class="menuButton" href='/'>
                <span class="menuTitleWrapper home">
                    <span class="menuTitle"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="menuButtonHolder" id="menu1">
            <a class="menuButton" href='/books'>
                <span class="menuTitleWrapper">
                    <span class="menuTitle"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>Books</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dt class="menuButtonHolder" id="menu2">
            <a class="menuButton" href='/resources'>
                <span class="menuTitleWrapper">
                    <span class="menuTitle"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>Resources</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </dt>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have a funny feeling it is this line that it does not like, even though my Console has no errors.

```
($this).parents('nav dl dt').addClass('menuOn');
```

`.parents(.selector-here).addClass. . .` is the right way to do this isn't it?

Comment: In your DOM you're writing `div` but in jquery your selector in first line starts with `nav`, intentional or mistake?

Comment: @SujitAgarwal It is wrapped in a `nav` yes. I have updated my code. :-)

Comment: Answered. Please try it out.

Comment: If you run the code in question it is working fine. Just for verify logic of `($this).parents('nav dl dt').addClass('menuOn');` commented `if` condition and checked. it's working as expected. You can check that with inspect element from browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest` to find the nearest `dt` -

```
var current = location.pathname;

$('nav dl dt a').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   // if the current path is like this link, make it active
   if($this.attr('href') == ('/' + current)){
       $(this).closest('dt').addClass('menuOn');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! When I am on the homepage `/` they all have `menuOn`, but when I am on the individual pages `/books/`, `/resources/` etc `menuOn` is not being applied? Any reason why that might be the case?

Comment: I've added a little change to the if condition. Please check

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Note that `<a>` elements also have `pathname` property the same as `location`which allows for equality comparison.

Then look for `closest('dt')` on filtered collection

```
$('nav dl dt a').filter(function(){
   return this.pathname === location.pathname;  
}).closest('dt').addClass('menuOn');
```

[Demo using hard code location.pathname variable](http://jsfiddle.net/0f4q8a5x/)

Comment: shouldn't that be `return this.href === current`?

Comment: @SujitAgarwal no because current is `pathname` not `href`. An `<a>` has same properties as location

Comment: but the filter function would set `this` to the currently being mapped anchor tag from the selector? Am I understanding things wrongly here?

Comment: if that's correct, then the current value of `this` is the anchor tag, so we need to access the href value of the anchor, not the pathname, am I correct?

Comment: Got it. I had totally forgot that anchor tags also have the pathname property. :D my bad

Comment: @SujitAgarwal Right...i stated that above that `<a>` has same properties as `location`. Lots of people aren't conscious of it because you don't use them very often and can do other things to accompish same task

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl very much. Is there an easy way to make this rule apply to the first folder. For example if I had `/books/best-sellers.aspx`, the button does not show `menuOn`, can I use `.split("/")[1]` or similar? Thanks again!

Comment: @cmp Can add any logic you want inside filter and return a boolean. Current approach is certainly the simplest case. So could be something like `if(this.pathname.includes('best-sellers')){ return false;}else(return this.pathname === location.pathname;}`